# How do I make an input radio button checked...using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="radio" name="sort" value="2" id="myradio">
```

How do I make this checked in JQUERY?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
$('#idOfMyRadio').attr('checked',true);
```

Comment: This will work, but the official attribute is .attr("checked", "checked");

Comment: Just as an update for more current versions of jQuery: "The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method."

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 6):

Really, there's no need for jQuery here: it will be slower, introduce a needless framework dependency and increase the possibility of error. The DOM method for this is also as clear and readable as it could be, and works in all the major browsers back to the 1990s:

```
document.getElementById("myradio").checked = true;
```

If you must use jQuery then I'd stop at just using it to get hold of the element:

```
$("#myradio")[0].checked = true;
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to using id...

```
$('input[name="sort"]').attr('checked',true);
$('input[value="2"]').attr('checked',true);
```

Comment: -1. Both will almost certainly be slower than using the id selector. The id selector can optimize and use `document.getElementById`, which is fast, while these will have to iterate over all the inputs in the document and check attribute values for each. Also, it's less precisely targetted: other radio buttons in the page that you're not intentionally targetting could perfectly well have a `name` of "sort" or a `value` of 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#idOfMyRadio').prop('checked',true);
```